# is there a cdn for the lastest jquery with a cache time?

Tags: jquery, cdn

jquery gives you the possibility to do a:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

the problem is that file hasn't any expiration date, so the client will always require it.

The other option is `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/x.x.x/jquery.min.js` that has a 1year expire

So, someone know a cdn offering a jquery-latest.js with some cache time?

Comment: Why is cache time an issue while it is not on your server? In case of CDN it is an issue between the end user and the CDN, why would you worry about that? Besides that, the end-user can always request a fresh document, if he wants to, or decide to use an old cached one.

Comment: Do you really want to use the latest version of jQuery rather than a specific version that you have tested against your software?

Comment: It has to be this way (no cache), since that URL may serve different bits at any time. A fully qualified version number will serve the same bits now and in the future, so any length of cache should be fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No.

The reason that specifying a far-future expires header improves performance is that the browser can immediately use a local copy of that file if it's within the expires timeframe.  The browser won't make an HTTP request at all in that case, not even to check for a 304 "Not Modified" response.

That means a "latest version" reference cannot be served with a performance-optimized expires header.  If it were, there would be no guarantee at all which version of the file any given browser might be using for the reference.

In production, you should always use the fully qualified x.y.z version number, and not one of the "get latest" references.  Google's CDN serves jQuery with a **+1 year** expires header when you reference it that way, which combined with the cross-site caching potential of public CDNs, means that many of your users may never even need to make an HTTP request for jQuery on your site at all.

Comment: man i don't need an explanation of the how the cache works. And i totally disagree with you because even a 'jquery-lastest.js' could be served with an expire of +1h (developers just need to wait 1hour after the release of a new jquery to know it would be always updated on users cache, if that's a problem )

Comment: A +1 hour expires is much shorter than you should be aiming for in production, if you care about optimizing for performance (which is the point of a CDN).

Comment: Seems pretty simple to me.  If you need cachability, don't use the "latest" version.  The two seem mutually exclusive.